# Writing structure to a file gives me wrong result

Tags: c++

I am trying to write to a named pipe (so we can say it's a file).

I am writing this structure to my file :

```
struct ProcessData
{
    int _processNumber;
    int _threadStatus;
};
```

`processNumber` and `threadStatus` are initialized to 0.

I am writing my structure this way :

```
  if (write(this->_fd, &data, sizeof(ProcessData)) == -1)
  {
    std::cerr << "Write failed" << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

and reading this way :

```
#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main()
{
  int fd;
  char * myfifo = "/tmp/the_plazza";
  char buf[MAX_BUF];

  /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
  fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
  read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
  printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
  close(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

But the output I receive is not good :

```
 /tmp  ./a.out | hexdump 
0000000 6552 6563 7669 6465 203a 000a          
000000b
```

Have any idea why ?

Comment: Your data is not a string, so printing it with %s will not work.

Comment: Post the contents of `data` - or how it was filled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't print the value of binary structure as if it was a string. And you do not need to read into the intermediate buffer. Just read directly into the variable of your type:

```
  ProcessData val;
  fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
  read(fd, &val, sizeof(val));
  std::cout << val._processNumber;
```

Answer (score 3):

You write raw binary data, and after you read it you treat it as a string. That simply will not work. Either you write as a (set) string and read as a set of string, *or* you write it as raw binary and read as raw binary data.

Comment: This is close, but technically not correct. OP is not trying to **read** it as string, but is treating the result as if it was a string.

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate what the others have said, you've stored the *binary representation* of a `struct` containing two `int` values, but you're reading it back in as an array of `char` and attempting to display it as a string.  What are you *expecting* to see as your output?  Hint: it won't be `"00"`.

There's another issue that needs to be addressed, though.  Reading and writing binary representations of `struct` types works as long as the reader and writer are on the same platform, but as soon as you try to write from one platform and read from another, you run into trouble.  Type sizes may differ, endianness may differ, alignment requirements may differ, etc.  You may want to read up on [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) techniques.